# Build multiple images of spring boot app with different tags using palantir plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, gradle

I am working on Spring Boot app and now I need to build docker images using palantir plugin.
I have managed to build an image and push it on DockerHub, everything works very well.
My question is, can I build two same images with different tag at the same time using palantir plugin in gradle.build?

My example of code from gradle.build is below:

```
bootJar {
    archiveName 'app.jar'
}

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.example.application.MyApplication'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

docker {
    dependsOn bootJar
    name "applicationName"
    files bootJar.archivePath
    tag 'DockerHub', "Repo/application:${project.version}"
}
```

- result of command
  **gradle dockerPushDockerHub** should be to make two same images with tags *0.0.1* and *latest* for example. And when I go on DockerHub to see both images there.

Thanks a lot...